# Creating a network with a specific name inside a container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, containers, entry-point

I would like to create a new container that has a new Network interface called cifx0.

I have created a Dockerfile including the entrypoint.

My Question is: can I build an entrypoint.sh file like this:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

ip link add cifx0 type bridge
ip link set cifx0 up
ip addr add (x.x.x.x)/24 dev cifx0
```

the image was created but when running the container it gave me error from entrypoint.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You don't get to control the names of network interfaces inside containers.  If you need this level of control over the networking setup, a virtual machine would be a better match.

Comment: Its just a simple question can i build my shell script like this and put it in the Entrypoint of my dockerfile?